# How to use PEP440 beta tags with setuptools_scm?

Tags: python, setuptools, setuptools-scm

Is there a way to use PEP440-style beta release tags, such as `v0.1.3b0` with setuptools_scm?

It currently gives an error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3b0'`.

This is from version 5.0.1 of setuptools_scm, which is the most recent as of today.

Comment: Hm, not sure what's up there. Seems that [`DEFAULT_TAG_REGEX`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm/blob/b8451688b9cb295136c0154c7c59c25a9d88f844/src/setuptools_scm/config.py#L9) does match your version.